# LDAP SSL client not sending hello packet

Tags: linux, authentication, ssl, ldap, pam

I'm trying to make LDAP setup using CentOS based OpenLDAP server and MCP Linux based PAM LDAP client.

Without SSL, I'm able to get the user authenticated successfully.

But with SSL('ssl start_tls' in /etc/pam_ldap.conf), I'm unable to get the user authenticated. When I did packet capture at server, I do not see client's HELLO packet.

Also, I'm not interested in server/client certificate verification hence at server I had 'TLSVerifyClient never' and at client I used 'TLS_REQCERT never' in /etc/openldap/ldap.conf(in addition to 'tls_checkpeer no' in /etc/pam_ldap.conf)

With CentOS based PAM LDAP client and with the same client configuration, I'm able to get the user authenticated successfully with the same server.

Can anyone tell me, in which cases SSL client doesn't send 'HELLO' packet ?

Here you go with logs at server:

...
connection_read(13): checking for input on id=1005
tls_read: want=3, got=0

TLS: error: accept - force handshake failure: errno 11 - moznss error -5938
TLS: can't accept: TLS error -5938:Encountered end of file.
connection_read(13): TLS accept failure error=-1 id=1005, closing
connection_closing: readying conn=1005 sd=13 for close
....

BTW, I'm trying to connect to client using SSH.

Also, if I use 'openssl s_client -connect my-domain.com:636 -showcerts -state -CAfile /etc/pki/tls/certs/cacert.pem' command at CLIENT, it is sending Client hello packet and is returing the server certificates

Thanks,
Sravani

Comment: Why aren't you interested in authentication? SSL isn't secure without it.

Comment: Hi EJP, Right now, I'm trying to get the setup without server/client certificate verification and just with user authentication. Once this is successful, I'll go to the next step of certificate verification. Thanks,Sravani

Comment: I *strongly* recommend you don't. It's extra code that is insecure. I'm convinced that quite a lot of these 'temporary fixes for debugging' have leaked into production, and caused deployed systems to be radically insecure as a result. If you don't write it, you can't leak it.

Comment: Hi EJP, Even after enabling Server certificate validation(using 'tls_checkpeer yes' in /etc/pam_ldap.conf and 'TLS_REQCERT demand' in /etc/openldap/ldap.conf), Client is not sending HELLO packet. Have you any idea why ?

Comment: Also, if I use 'openssl s_client -connect my-domain.com:636 -showcerts -state -CAfile /etc/pki/tls/certs/cacert.pem' command at CLIENT, it is sending Client hello packet and is returing the server certificates.

Answer (score -1):

From 'strace ldapsearch ....' log, I see that 
open("/usr/lib/libsoftokn3.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I'll try to get this library for MCP Linux and give it a try again.

Thanks all for your support